# System.OutOfMemory exception after hours of running

Tags: vb.net, out-of-memory, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I made a program to read Exchange emails, export them as PDF and save the operation to an Access database:

```
Imports Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    'Database connection and Exchange service
    Public Exchange As ExchangeService
    Dim inboxDBCon As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Inboxdb.accdb")
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dre As OleDbDataReader

    'Total  amount of emails in exchange server
    Dim ExchangeInboxEmailsTotalCount As Integer = 0
    ' Amount of emails processed by the program
    Dim InboxEmailsProcessedCount As Integer = 0
    ' Total amount of emails in the database
    Dim DatabaseInboxEmailsCount As Integer = 0

    ' Timers definitions
    Private inboxBackgroundWorker As New BackgroundWorker
    Dim programPaused = False

    'Paths
    Dim inboxPath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Inbox/"

    'Other vars
    Dim int_load_time As Int32 = 30
    Dim pro As New PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.Id, EmailMessageSchema.Subject, EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeReceived, EmailMessageSchema.DateTimeSent, EmailMessageSchema.Body, EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent, EmailMessageSchema.Sender, EmailMessageSchema.From, EmailMessageSchema.HasAttachments, EmailMessageSchema.ToRecipients)
    Dim canadaTimeZon As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time") 'modify in November for: Eastern Daylight Time
    Dim duplicateds As Integer = 0

    ' Form loading
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Setup grids
        lblStatus.Text = "Drawing components"
        Me.lstMsg.Rows.Clear()
        lstMsg.ReadOnly = True
        lstMsg.RowHeadersVisible = False
        lstMsg.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        Me.lstMsg.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One
        lstMsg.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
        lstMsg.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
        lstMsg.Sort(lstMsg.Columns(1), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        lblRemainingInboxEmail.Text = "0"
        lblExchangeInboxCount.Text = "0"
        pro.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text

        ' Connect to Exchange
        lblStatus.Text = "Connecting to Exchange server"
        lblcountSkipped.Text = duplicateds.ToString()
        Try
            If inboxDBCon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                inboxDBCon.Open()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error while opening database. Please check whether the database exist and is not opened")
            Application.Exit()
        End Try

        ' Read inbox count from access database
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM t_email_inbox;", inboxDBCon)
        DatabaseInboxEmailsCount = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        inboxDBCon.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()

        ' Display counts obtained from access databases
        lblInbox.Text = DatabaseInboxEmailsCount.ToString()

        ConnectToExchangeServer()
    End Sub

    ' Connect to Exchange server
    Public Sub ConnectToExchangeServer()
        Try
            Exchange = New ExchangeService(canadaTimeZon)
            'Exchange.TraceEnabled = True
            Exchange.Credentials = New WebCredentials("SoftwareTest@ivy-cpa.com", "XXXXXXXXXX", "ivy-cpa.com")
            Exchange.Url = New System.Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx")
            lblStatus.Text = "Connection Established"
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblStatus.Text = "Connection to Exchange failed"
            MsgBox("Fatal Error in Connect: " & ex.Message)
            End
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartReaingdInbox(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
        Try
            ReadInbox()
        Catch ex As Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException
            Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                            lblStatus.Text = "WRONG EXCHANGE CREDENTIALS!"
                                        End Sub))
            InboxTimer.Enabled = False
            programPaused = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            If inboxDBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                inboxDBCon.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub InboxReadingCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        'Add your codes for the worker to execute after finishing the work.
        InboxTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub InboxTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InboxTimer.Tick
        Try
            If Not programPaused Then
                If int_load_time > 0 Then
                    int_load_time -= 10
                    lblStatus.Text = int_load_time.ToString() + " sec"
                    Return
                End If

                int_load_time = 30
                lblStatus.Text = "Fetching emails..."
                InboxTimer.Enabled = False
                If Not inboxBackgroundWorker.IsBusy Then
                    'inboxBackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
                    AddHandler inboxBackgroundWorker.DoWork, AddressOf StartReaingdInbox
                    AddHandler inboxBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf InboxReadingCompleted
                    inboxBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.ToString().ToLower().Contains("Connection was not closed") Then
                inboxDBCon.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReadInbox()
        Try
            If programPaused Then
                Return
            End If
            Dim file_path As String = ""
            Dim attach_path As String = ""
            Dim Message As EmailMessage = Nothing
            Dim cadTime As Date = Nothing
            Dim startDate As Date = Nothing
            Dim startIndex = 0

            If inboxDBCon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                inboxDBCon.Open()
            End If

            cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM t_email_inbox ORDER BY Date DESC", inboxDBCon)
            dre = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dre.Read() Then
                startDate = dre("Date")
            End If
            inboxDBCon.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()

            If Exchange IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim pageSize = 100
                Dim view = New ItemView(pageSize)
                view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending)
                Dim exchangeFilter As SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo = New SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, startDate)
                ExchangeInboxEmailsTotalCount = Exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view).TotalCount
                Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                                lblExchangeInboxCount.Text = ExchangeInboxEmailsTotalCount.ToString()
                                            End Sub))
                'ExchangeInboxEmailsTotalCount = Exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, exchangeFilter, view).TotalCount

                Dim moreItems = True
                Dim anchorId = ""
                view = New ItemView(pageSize, startIndex)
                view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Ascending)
                While (moreItems)
                    Dim results As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = Exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, exchangeFilter, view)
                    moreItems = results.MoreAvailable
                    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                                    indexlbl.Text = "Processing this session: " + results.TotalCount.ToString()
                                                End Sub))

                    If moreItems AndAlso anchorId <> "" Then
                        If results.Items.First().Id.UniqueId <> anchorId Then
                            Console.[Error].WriteLine("The collection has changed while paging. Some results may be missed.")
                        End If
                    End If

                    If moreItems Then
                        view.Offset += pageSize
                    End If

                    anchorId = results.Items.Last().Id.UniqueId
                    Dim displayCount As Integer = If(results.Items.Count > pageSize, pageSize, results.Items.Count)

                    For i As Integer = 0 To displayCount - 1
                        If startIndex > ExchangeInboxEmailsTotalCount Then
                            Return
                        End If

                        Dim MyItem As Item = results.Items(i)
                        Dim subj = MyItem.Subject
                        Try
                            Message = EmailMessage.Bind(Exchange, MyItem.Id, pro)

                            ' Create data
                            cadTime = Message.DateTimeReceived
                            Dim FromName = ReplaceInvalidChars(Message.From.Name.ToString())
                            Dim file_folder As String = inboxPath & FromName & "_" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "") & "/"
                            file_path = file_folder & FromName & "_" & cadTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy") & "--" & cadTime.ToLongTimeString().Replace(":", "_") & ".pdf"
                            Dim Subject = If(Message.Subject Is Nothing, "No Subject", Message.Subject.ToString())
                            Dim Body = If(Message.Body Is Nothing, "No Body", Message.Body.ToString())

                            ' Set recipients
                            Dim Recipients As String = ""
                            For Each rec As EmailAddress In Message.ToRecipients
                                Recipients += rec.Address.ToString() + ","
                            Next
                            If Recipients = "" Then
                                Recipients = "No Recipients "
                            End If
                            Try
                                Recipients = Recipients.Remove(Recipients.Length - 1, 1)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                            End Try

                            ' Check if duplicated
                            Try
                                If inboxDBCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                                    inboxDBCon.Open()
                                End If
                                cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM t_email_inbox WHERE Date=@date AND From=@from AND Subject=@subject AND To_Recipients=@recipients AND body=@body", inboxDBCon)
                                'cadTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(MyItem.DateTimeReceived, canadaTimeZon)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", cadTime)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Message.From.Name.ToString())
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject", Subject)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recipients", Recipients.ToString())
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@body", Body)
                                dre = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                                If dre.Read() Then
                                    duplicateds += 1
                                    Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                                                    lblcountSkipped.Text = duplicateds.ToString()
                                                                End Sub))
                                    Debug.WriteLine("Skipping duplicated email " + duplicateds.ToString())
                                    ' Calculate index
                                    startDate = cadTime
                                    startIndex = startIndex + 1
                                    Continue For
                                End If
                                inboxDBCon.Close()
                                cmd.Dispose()
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Console.Error.WriteLine("The sql query failed")
                            End Try

                            ' Create path to write
                            Try
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(file_folder)
                            Catch ex As Exception
                                Debug.WriteLine("exception creating directory")
                            End Try

                            ' Check attachments
                            For Each attach As Attachment In Message.Attachments
                                Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(file_folder & attach.Name, FileMode.Create)
                                Dim w As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(fs)
                                Dim FileAttachment As FileAttachment = attach
                                FileAttachment.Load()
                                Console.WriteLine("FileName: " + FileAttachment.Name)
                                w.Write(FileAttachment.Content)
                                fs.Close()
                                fs.Dispose()
                                w.Dispose()
                            Next

                            ' Message save
                            Dim MsgFs As FileStream = New FileStream(file_path.Replace(".pdf", ".eml"), FileMode.Create)
                            MsgFs.Write(Message.MimeContent.Content, 0, Message.MimeContent.Content.Length)
                            MsgFs.Close()
                            MsgFs.Dispose()

                            ' Write PDF
                            Dim doc As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35)
                            Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New FileStream(file_path, FileMode.Create))
                            doc.Open()
                            Dim table As New PdfPTable(7)
                            table.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0
                            Dim Calibri8 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)
                            Dim Calibri8Normal As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
                            table.DefaultCell.Border = 0
                            table.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("From: ", Calibri8)) With {.BorderWidth = 0, .VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER})
                            table.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase(Message.From.Name, Calibri8Normal)) With {.Colspan = 6, .BorderWidth = 0, .VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER})
                            table.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Recieved: ", Calibri8)) With {.BorderWidth = 0, .VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER})
                            table.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase(cadTime.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt"), Calibri8Normal)) With {.Colspan = 6, .BorderWidth = 0, .VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER})
                            table.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Recipients: ", Calibri8)) With {.BorderWidth = 0, .VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER})
                            table.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase(Recipients, Calibri8Normal)) With {.Colspan = 6, .BorderWidth = 0, .VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER})
                            table.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase("Subject: ", Calibri8)) With {.BorderWidth = 0, .VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER})
                            table.AddCell(New PdfPCell(New Phrase(Subject, Calibri8Normal)) With {.Colspan = 6, .BorderWidth = 0, .VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER})
                            doc.Add(table)
                            Dim para As New Paragraph(Message.Body)
                            doc.Add(para)
                            doc.Close()
                            writer.Close()
                            doc.Dispose()
                            writer.Dispose()

                            ' Insert to DB
                            If inboxDBCon.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                                inboxDBCon.Open()
                            End If
                            cmd = New OleDbCommand("insert into t_email_inbox([date],[from],subject,attach,body,file_path,outlook_id,To_Recipients) 
                        values(@date,@from,@subject,@attach,@body,@file_path,@outlook,@recps)", inboxDBCon)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", cadTime) '.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"))
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("from", Message.From.Name.ToString())
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("subject", Subject)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("attach", Message.HasAttachments.ToString())
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("body", Body)
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("file_path", file_folder.ToString())
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("outlook", Message.Id.UniqueId.ToString())
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("recps", Recipients.ToString())
                            ' cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("attach_folder", "")
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            inboxDBCon.Close()
                            cmd.Dispose()

                            Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                                            lstMsg.Rows.Add(cadTime, Message.From.Name.ToString(), Message.Subject, Message.Body, Message.HasAttachments.ToString())
                                                            DatabaseInboxEmailsCount += 1
                                                            InboxEmailsProcessedCount += 1
                                                            lblInbox.Text = DatabaseInboxEmailsCount.ToString()
                                                            lblRemainingInboxEmail.Text = InboxEmailsProcessedCount.ToString()
                                                            lstMsg.Sort(lstMsg.Columns(0), ListSortDirection.Descending)
                                                        End Sub))

                            ' Calculate index
                            startDate = cadTime
                            startIndex += 1

                        Catch ex As Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException
                            i -= 1
                            Continue For
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                            Debug.WriteLine(ex.GetType())
                            If inboxDBCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                                inboxDBCon.Close()
                                inboxDBCon.Dispose()
                            End If
                        End Try
                    Next
                End While
            Else
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Function ReplaceInvalidChars(ByVal filename As String) As String
        Return String.Join("_", filename.Split(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()))
    End Function

    Private Sub lstMsg_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstMsg.SelectionChanged
        Try
            Dim i = lstMsg.CurrentRow.Index
            txtInboxBody.Text = lstMsg.Item(3, i).Value.ToString()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("exception selecting row")
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I don't know why it's crashing after 10+ hours of running, throwing a System.OutOfMemory exception...

I'm not sure what could cause it...

I've added the `SetProcessWorkingSetSize` function but it just made the program slower... I just ended up by doing an auto-restarter but that's dirty and bad.

What could cause this program to crash by a System.OutOfMemory exception after that long time of running?

Comment: That's a lot of code...  Are you disposing everything that can be disposed after using?  e.g.  Dim table As New PdfPTable(7)  ALSO, what line throws the error?

Comment: Yes sorry it's a lot of code... I was trying to dispose everything. I don't know how to dispose the PdfPTable I don't see a Dispose() method

Comment: As far as I can see I disposed everything

Comment: Maybe what might get you closer is creating new instances of the objects that implement IDisposable with a Using clause rather than reusing the form level fields.  Looking at inboxDBCon , cmd and dre for a start.  There may well be more.  Also see a Background worker in there that at first glance can't see doing much

Comment: Since it is a bit of a code wall. You might try and use something called BenchmarkDotNet it has a NuGet package. https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/getting-started.html.

I would seriously suggest splitting up some of these methods as well if you go down this route. Even if it feels like just moving code around it will help with finding which parts are increasing memory usage drastically.